# Mapping a function to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I was trying to apply a function to a dataframe in pandas. I am trying to take two columns as positional arguments and map a function to it. Below is the code I tried.
Code:

```
df_a=pd.read_csv('5_a.csv')
def y_pred(x):
    if x<.5:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1
df_a['y_pred']=df_a['proba'].map(y_pred)
def confusion_matrix(act,pred):
    if act==1 and act==pred:
        return 'TP'
    elif act==0 and act==pred:
        return 'TN'
    elif act==0 and pred==1:
        return 'FN'
    elif act==1 and pred==0:
        return 'FP'
df_a['con_mat_label']=df_a[['y','y_pred']].apply(confusion_matrix)
```

But the function is not considering `y_pred` as the second column and mapping it to pred variable in the defined function.
I am gettting this error:
`TypeError: ("confusion_matrix() missing 1 required positional argument: 'pred'", 'occurred at index y')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you get as argument in the function that you pass as part of `apply` method is a `pandas series` and using the `axis` argument you can specify if has to be a `row` or a `column`.

So you need to modify your `confusion_matrix` function to

- I am assuming that the `act` corresponds to the column name `y` here*

```py
def confusion_matrix(row):
    if row.y==1 and row.y==row.y_pred:
        return 'TP'
    elif row.y==0 and row.y==row.y_pred:
        return 'TN'
    elif row.y==0 and row.y_pred==1:
        return 'FN'
    elif row.y==1 and row.y_pred==0:
        return 'FP'
```

---

And you need to modify your `apply` call to

```py
df_a['con_mat_label']=df_a[['y','y_pred']].apply(confusion_matrix, axis=1)
```

---

Now let me give you some tips on how you could improve your code.

Say you have a data frame like this:

```
>>> df
   X  Y
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6
3  4  7
```

To add a `Y_pred` column

```
>>> df['Y_pred'] = (df.X < 3).astype(int)
>>> df
   X  Y  Y_pred
0  1  4       1
1  2  5       1
2  3  6       0
3  4  7       0
```

Oh btw, I would like you to refer you to this interesting blog [post](https://maxpowerwastaken.github.io/blog/pandas-dont-apply-_-vectorize/)

Answer (score 1):

The apply function take each column one by one, run it through the function and return an transformed column. Here are more documentation on it [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).
Your setup would be better for a list comprehension. Here how you can get the intended behavior:

```py
df_a['con_mat_label'] = [confusion_matrix(act,pred) for (act,pred) in df[['y','y_pred']].to_numpy()]
```

Hope it helps!